# PayPal Orders v2: Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, guzzle

I am trying to use PayPal API. Here is the reference of Curl usage: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/

After searching in google, I found a link that shows a similar error: but, no hints given to fix it. https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/Request-is-not-well-formed-syntactically-incorrect-or-violates/td-p/2090480

**I have following code in PHP and Laravel**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer " . $this->token
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            "intent" => "CAPTURE",
            "purchase_units" => [
                "amount" => [
                    "currency_code" => "USD",
                    "value" => "100.00"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

When I run the code, I get the following error

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException Client error: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is
> not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates
> schema.","debug_id (truncated...)

**Update 1 - Modified the code as told in answer, But still same error message**

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer " . $this->token
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            "intent" => "CAPTURE",
            "purchase_units" => [
                [
                    "amount" => [
                        "currency_code" => "USD",
                        "value" => "100.00"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: My guess would be that you're telling the request it's json `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'`, but you're adding the data like if it was form-data. Try and send the data as json instead (json_encode the data and put it directly in the request body)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - can you please check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483806/paypal-order-api-not-processing-approve-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Below code works for me.**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
        'json' => [
            "intent" => "CAPTURE",
            "purchase_units" => [
                [
                    "amount" => [
                        "currency_code" => "USD",
                        "value" => "100.00"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer " . $this->token
        ]
    ]            
);
```

Comment: How can I add items in the purchase units array, this code working file for me. But when I tries to add items(using other docs) it gives me 400 error again.

Answer (score 0):

The document said:

> purchase_units: array (contains the purchase_unit object)
> An array of purchase units. Each purchase unit establishes a contract between a customer and merchant. Each purchase unit represents either a full or partial order that the customer intends to purchase from the merchant.

Your purchase_units right now is the purchase_unit, not an array of purchase_unit, try changing your form_params to

```
[
    "intent" => "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units" => [
       [ 
          "amount" => [
            "currency_code" => "USD",
            "value" => "100.00"
          ]
       ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Still same error message, please check the updated question.

Comment: can you please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483806/paypal-order-api-not-processing-approve-url

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     'form_params' => [
> ```

The PayPal REST API does not use form parameters.

You need to send a 'json' data object. See the [GuzzleHttp client documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json).

Comment: can you please check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483806/paypal-order-api-not-processing-approve-url