# paypal sandbox api v2 stuck in checkout

Tags: curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i'm working on implementing a paypal checkout via the paypal api v2 in sandbox mode. I can generated my payment link and the buyer can log in, but when i click on continue in the checkout it just says processing und then goes back to the same checkout page as before. No money is being transfered. Any ideas what the problem could be? Thanks in advance. I'm using this curl request to generate the payment:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer A21AALHTf1wswCyoKRV-dDMnaZQsI7P2Q6zdefcBniEZg7aBYGt6AUn7JmfQ5dnwfwvMtSPxxjbgDecE5-fwPPwWMzUfUMQTA" \
-d '{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PayPal Orders V2 not processing approve url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483806/paypal-orders-v2-not-processing-approve-url)

Comment: Thanks but no. My problem is not that it doesnt redirect, but that no money is been transfered

Comment: Both are not happening. First you must redirect, then you must capture. You are not doing either.

Comment: Sry for late response, but I was sick the last days. I tried adding  "application_context":{
  "return_url":"https://example.com/",
  "cancel_url":"https://example.com/"
 },
 but now i get MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON. How can i redirect correctly?

Comment: Use valid http URLs

Comment: tried    "application_context":{
  "return_url":"https://google.com/",
  "cancel_url":"https://google.com/"
 }, same result

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code.

```
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
            "application_context":{
                "user_action":"PAY_NOW",
                "return_url":"https://demo.com/",
                "cancel_url":"https://demo.com/"
            },
            "purchase_units": [
              {
                "amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100.00"
                }
              }
            ],
```